# c++ ceil() in stooge sort not working

Tags: c++, sorting, ceil

I am implementing a stooge sort.

```
void stoogeSort(int arr[], int low, int high)
{   
    int size = high - low + 1;

    if (size == 2 && arr[0] > arr[1])
    {
        int temp = arr[0];
        arr[0] = arr[1];
        arr[1] = temp;
    }

    else if (size > 2)
    {
        int mid = (int) ceil((2 * size) / 3);
        stoogeSort(arr, low, mid - 1);
        stoogeSort(arr, size - mid, high);
        stoogeSort(arr, low, mid - 1);
    }
}
```

There seems to be a problem at `int mid = (int) ceil((2 * size) / 3)` as it is not returning the right number.  For example, if size is calculated to be 4, mid should hold 3 as the ceiling of (2 * 4) / 3 is 3.  However, it holds 2.

I have `#include <cmath>` and `using std::ceil` below that.  No matter what kind of type conversion I do, it either holds the wrong number or ends up throwing a stack overflow error at the top of this function.  Any ideas? Thank you!

**NOTE: Changing the 3 to 3.0 results in a stack overflow error at the top of the function**

Comment: The `(2 * size) /3` expression is an integer.  So `ceil` doesn't have much to do, since the int expression has already truncated fractional values (effectively).

Comment: @Eljay changing the 3 to 3.0 ends up throwing a stack overflow error at the top of the fuction

Comment: What does the call stack look like then?  That should show you the flaw in your logic.

Comment: call stack shows that the 2nd recursive call is where it gets stuck. size - mid is wrong I think but not sure why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int mid = (int) ceil((2 * size) / 3);
```

You're doing an integer division and passing the result to `ceil()`.  Hence, the `ceil()` call has no effect.

Try something like this instead:

```
int mid = ((2 * size) + 2) / 3;
```

---

That will not solve your real problem, though.  There are several errors in your algorithm.  Going with the implementation in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stooge_sort) this part:

```
if (size == 2 && arr[0] > arr[1])
{
    int temp = arr[0];
    arr[0] = arr[1];
    arr[1] = temp;
}
```

should be something like this:

```
if (arr[low] > arr[high])
{
    std::swap(arr[low], arr[high]);
}
```

This part :

```
else if (size > 2)
```

should be :

```
if (size > 2)
```

This :

```
int mid = (int) ceil((2 * size) / 3);
```

should be :

```
int mid = size / 3;
```

and this :

```
stoogeSort(arr, low, mid - 1);
stoogeSort(arr, size - mid, high);
stoogeSort(arr, low, mid - 1);
```

should be:

```
stoogeSort(arr, low, high - mid);
stoogeSort(arr, low + mid, high);
stoogeSort(arr, low, high - mid);
```

You should note that `mid` is not the index of the middle element.  It is a size that you add to `low` or subtract from `high`.  It may be smaller than `low`.  Hence, the name `mid` is misleading.

---

Stitching it all together you get this:

```
void stoogeSort(int arr[], int low, int high)
{   
    if (arr[low] > arr[high])
    {
        std::swap(arr[low], arr[high]);
    }
    int size = high - low + 1;
    if (size > 2)
    {
        int mid = size / 3;
        stoogeSort(arr, low, high - mid);
        stoogeSort(arr, low + mid, high);
        stoogeSort(arr, low, high - mid);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input! but doing (2 * size) + 2 / 3 is basically the same as `ceil((2 * size) / 3.0)` which is where I am currently at. there is something wrong with the 2nd recursive call

Comment: Do you expect me to answer the question you have posted, or guess where you are currently "at" ?  Either way, there is no need to complicate things by introducing floating point and what I suggested is more efficient than what you're at.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to be ambiguous or anything.  I understand what you are saying now and this worked very well. I was actually given the pseudo-code for this algorithm and it had mid as `(2 * size) / 3`.  But it makes much more sense just to do `size / 3`, evenly cutting the array into thirds.  Thanks again!